# Google fonts and font-display

Tags: css, font-face, google-fonts

We are currently loading a couple of fonts on our site from google fonts using the following link

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons%7CRoboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,700&display=block">
```

As you can see, at the end of the query string, we have `display=block` to stop the font from rendering before it's loaded (as it adds `font-display: block`).  However, this adds block to all declarations of every font face.  Is there a way to only add this to the material icons font without having to make 2 separate requests?

Comment: Not sure it is possible at the moment. I think you have couple options: 1. Make 2 requests (the one you mentioned) 2. Host the font yourself (you can download). Maybe this article will open other options -> https://medium.com/@jirafe/supercharge-google-fonts-with-cloudflare-and-service-workers-25c37462fb6a

Comment: Maybe loading each font using a different link will solve the problem. Keep `display=block` on the link you need it on.